# Is there a way to relate channel fields to one another?

Tags: channel-fields

I am creating a staff profile page, where I want to display social media icons for any social media sites each staff member may have (see photo).

I don't want to list ALL social media options, but I'd rather have a channel field type "drop-down" with options, and then a corresponding URL field (which can just be a text field).  If the user has more than one social media account, there should be a "add another" button on the Publish page, which will add another drop-down and URL field.

The drop-down field will correspond to a Class name (i.e. class="icon-facebook"), which will then place an icon on the published page.

Is this possible, or am I making this too complicated?

[image: Final Product]
[image: My Code]

Is there another, better solution in order to make this work?  Or would it be easier for me to hard-code a "Facebook" field, and a "Facebook_url" field, "twitter," "twitter_url," etc.?

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the Grid fieldtype?
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html

edit: if you need extra validation based on one of the columns (e.g. if an image is selected, validate that a caption is required), then you can insert some jQuery or javascript in a custom accesoire, or more simple, inside the field instructions. Be careful (and test) because the field-instructions do get formatted a bit (e.g. nbsp; inserted).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    console.log('hello console');
});
</script>
Other normal instruction text
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom_grid_validate.js"></script>
Other normal instructions
```

Comment: That worked beautifully!  Thank you!  It took me a few minutes to figure out the field type, but it seems to be working.

Now, one more question...  I want the URL field to be a required field if one of the drop-downs is selected.  Is that possible, or would that require extra coding?

Comment: Yes, you can make a column in a grid-field required. But you cannot make a field required depending on a value of another field. However, you can make an accesoire with some javascript to validate this.

Comment: Great, thank you!  Very much appreciated!

Comment: Or you can add a script tag to the field instructions :-) instead of making a full accesoire. (example added to answer)